# Export csv with Async await in linq select issue

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, webassembly

I'm currently stuck with this issue, and really got 0 ideas on how to resolve it. So I'm basically calling the export function after setting this data. Without async and dummy data It works, on implementing this, I'm not able to export anything. This is what I've done by far, and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. IF you have any idea, please help me. I can also provide more code if needed.

[image: exception-screenshot]

this is the code:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable> OnExport(SearchCriteria cr)
    {
        var sr = await GetResult(cr);
        var results = sr.Results;
        var exportData = results.Select(async export =>
        {
            var data = await dataService.GetById(export.Id);
            var pAddress = export.ContactInformation?.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressType == Framework.Contracts.Enums.AddressTypes.Physical);
            var mAddress = export.ContactInformation?.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressType == Framework.Contracts.Enums.AddressTypes.Mailing);
            return new
            {
                LegalBusinessName = export.Name,
                DBA = export.DBAName,
                BusinessEmail = export.ContactInformation?.PrimaryEmail,
                PhonePrimary = export.ContactInformation?.PrimaryPhone,
                PhoneTypePrimary = export.ContactInformation?.PrimaryPhoneType,
                PhoneSecondary = export.ContactInformation?.SecondaryPhone,
                PhoneTypeSecondary = export.ContactInformation?.SecondaryPhoneType,
                Website = export.WebAddress,
                PhysicalStreetAddress = pAddress?.Address1,
                PhysicalAddressLine2 = pAddress?.Address2,
                PhysicalCity = pAddress?.City,
                PhysicalCounty = pAddress?.County,
                PhysicalState = pAddress?.State,
                PhysicalZipCode = pAddress?.Zip,
                MailingStreetAddress = mAddress?.Address1,
                MailingAddressLine2 = mAddress?.Address2,
                MailingCity = mAddress?.City,
                MailingCounty = mAddress?.County,
                MailingState = mAddress?.State,
                MailingZipCode = mAddress?.Zip,
                SchoolOnboarding = data?.ConfirmedVideo,
                SchoolStartDate = data?.SchoolStartDate,
                SchoolEndDate = data?.SchoolEndDate,
                Grades = string.Join(",", data?.GradeLevels.Select(x => x.GradeLevel)),
                IsReligiousSchool = data?.ConfirmedIsReligious,
                ReligiousAffiliation = data?.ReligiousAffiliation,
                TCSignatureName = export.SignatureName,
                TCDateSigned = export.TermsAcceptedOn
            };
        });

        return exportData;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you not specify what type is contained in your returned `IEnumerable`?

Comment: I think im not sure what exactly I should do

Comment: Maybe using an anonymous object with csvhelper creates this issue. Have you tried defining a class that you will use to store this data?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you try to export a System.Type

Definiton of System.Type: Represents type declarations: class types, interface types, array types, value types, enumeration types, type parameters, generic type definitions, and open or closed constructed generic types.

Check if your ExportData has any value that is not a string.

Comment: BPTab = null
ContactInf = Project.Info
Conta = Count = 1
DNa = 414c4143485541204c4541524e494e472041434144454d5920454c454d454e54415259
Des = 54686973206973207468652062657374205363486f6f4c204576457221
DirectPay = nullID
IsPayable = false
Name = 141414c2421534543sdfcr414
PaymentMet = count = 0
ProfileCom true
ProfileComp 4/13/2022
ProgrID count = 0
ProvidCo = null
ProvidTy = 32
SeqNum = 32
SigDat = null
SigUrl = null
SourSysPro = count = 0
taxId = null
taxidtype = null
Terms = count = 0
TermAccOn 4/5/2022
TermCompl = false
Type = null
weAdress = null
This is what i got